# How do a pass a function the row number of an embedded iframe?

Tags: jquery, select, iframe, row, parent

I have an table where every row has a hidden iframe on it.  When the iframe is done loading it should call a function that sits on the parent page (this works).  However, when the parent function is called I need to pass the row value... but since it is the iframe making the call I don't know how to get the row.

```
function myRowCallback(rowIndex){
    alert('row ' + rowIndex + ' is done loading');
}

<table>
   <tr>
       <td><iframe id='frame1' onload='myRowCallback($(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length)' style='display: none;'></td>
       <td><iframe id='frame2' onload='myRowCallback($(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length)' style='display: none;'></td>
       <td><iframe id='frame3' onload='myRowCallback($(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length)' style='display: none;'></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this as

```
<td>
  <iframe id='frame1' onload='parent.myRowCallback($(this).closest("tr").prevAll().length);' ></iframe>
</td>
```

use `parent.` to call parent function

Comment: The problem is with the 'tr' not being defined.  I am able to successfully call the parent function, I just can't pass it the row of the embedded iframe.

Comment: there is a problem with your syntax you use `tr` enclosed within `'`(single quotes), you have to enclosed your `tr` within `"`(double quotes), i corrected your syntax in my answer.so the correct one will be `.closest("tr")`